# Reporting services expression in column 1 not functioning correctly (BIDS 2005)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

This is an odd one! I have a simple table report with the following formula applied to the whole row

```
=iif(RowNumber(nothing) mod 2 = 0,"LightBlue","White")
```

This works fine in SSRS preview and when I export the report from the server to Excel. However, on the server itself the expression does not appear to be filling the column with the correct colour. The expression is present in the first column!
[image]

Comment: Is there a filter on the table?

Comment: hmm should work. try the hex code instead of the color names and check.

Comment: No filter @Jonnus. Simple as!

Comment: Have you tried adding as an extra expression (placeholder) in the cell the value of `RowNumber(nothing)` to ensure it is as you are expecting?

Comment: @BhupeshC. Tried a hex value. Same result!

Comment: I've added a first column @Jonnus with `RowNumber(nothing)' This provided the values I was expecting. If I use this column and reduce it to .079cm then the colouring for the rest of the report is now correct. However, if I hide this column completely then the problem returns!

Comment: is there any thing special about that column, any expression anywhere which is specific to this and only this column.

Comment: Not really @BhupeshC. It really is a simple report. Perhaps there's something odd with the way report server renders the report once deployed. My initial "waffer thin" column is OK with the user, so I'll go with this solution in the short term! Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my **alternating row colors** depend on **RowNumber** because it can have unpredictable results due to grouping, visibility...

I use some modified **Alternate Row Number** code:

```
Private bOddRow(10) As Boolean 

Function AlternateColor(ByVal OddColor As String, ByVal EvenColor As String, ByVal Toggle As Boolean, ByVal Type AS INTEGER) As String 

  If Toggle Then bOddRow(Type) = Not bOddRow(Type) 

  If bOddRow(Type) Then 
                Return OddColor 
  Else 
                Return EvenColor 
  End If 

End Function
```

In the expression, use:

```
=CODE.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 0, 0)
```

Except for the first column, where you need to use **1** for the **Toggle** value:

```
=CODE.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 1, 0)
```

The second number is used for multiple levels of grouping (which you don't have here). If this was a sub group, you would use a 1 for the next level to keep them separate.

```
=CODE.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 0, 1)
=CODE.AlternateColor("White", "AliceBlue", 1, 1)
```

Comment: Hannover Fist, that is a good approach since I've seen a lot of users facing unexpected behaviour while using `RowNumber` function to alternate colors. Let me steal it for my own KB.

Comment: Thanks @HannoverFist that looks really good ... but this still results in an all white first column on my report once deployed! This works fine in preview and Excel export. Must some odd rendering going on somewhere!